# System suspend by itself abnormally

Tags: 16.04, kernel, suspend

I am new to Linux system and when I finish installing Ubuntu 16.04, the system works fine at first. BUT When I close the lid, and re-open my lid, the computer cannot wake up.

Then I find someone has the same problem on this forum and learn to upgrade my kernel to 4.8.0 from the default kernel 4.4.0 following that post.THEN My computer can wake up after I re-open the lid! And the suspension problem seems solved.

However, then the computer begin to suspend by itself every several seconds. Every time I wake up it, and it just suspend again by itself (unless I choose 'do nothing' from 'suspend' in power settings). I read many posts, most of them are about cannot wake up after suspension, I haven't seen any person ask the same problem yet.

In short, my problem is: computer keep suspending itself every several seconds after I re-open my lid. I can solve the problem by turn off the 'suspend', but I hope I could find a way to solve this problem.

I am not a computer science student so I am still not at the level of debugging such problem by myself. Really appreciate it if someone could help me.

Comment: What kind of computer do you have ? What brand & model ?

Comment: Hi, I use Razer blade 2014 model, which use Intel 4720 CPU and Nvidia 980m GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I temporarily solve it by choose 'do nothing' when closing the lid in power settings, and then every time I use 'sudo pm-suspend' to suspend my system. (I find the computer works fine when I suspend by using terminal)

Still don't know the reason for my question.